# Continuous crossfade of images and out of memory

Tags: android, image

I have an activity that show some full screen images in crossfade. There are a total of 6 images. To do this I used 2 ImageViews and 2 animation playing at the same time, one that fades out the first image and one that fades in the second. I used this video as a reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XbKMUtVnJA

Because I need this to run continuously, I used a timer to schedule the animation every 4 seconds. Everything works, but it uses a huge quantity of memory. To load the images I tried:

- the basic not recommended way used in the video, i.e loading all images in a drawable array
- setting the images using imageview.setImageResource
- loading the images from assets using Picasso

All this method are memory intensive a cause an out of memory exception on older devices (like a Galaxy S2). The Picasso approach isn't working properly.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, but I don't know it, any suggestions?

Here's the relevant code:

```
private void animateImageview(){
    prevImageView.animate().alpha(0);
    nextImageView.animate().alpha(1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentDrawable =
                    (mCurrentDrawable + 1) % imagesToShow.length;
            int nextDrawableIndex =
                    (mCurrentDrawable + 1) % imagesToShow.length;
            prevImageView.setImageResource(imagesToShow[mCurrentDrawable]);

            nextImageView.setImageResource(imagesToShow[nextDrawableIndex]);

            nextImageView.setAlpha(0f);
            prevImageView.setAlpha(1f);
        }
    });

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

prevImageView.setImageResource(imagesToShow[0]);
nextImageView.setImageResource(imagesToShow[1]);

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animateImageview();
        }
    }, 5000, 4000);

}
```

**Edit:**
the largeHeap option in the manifest seems to solve the problem, but I'm not convinced that I'm doing this thing right anyway.

**Edit2:**
A gist with the solution I used https://gist.github.com/alexmazza/003e3449c02fe58848a9

Comment: What is the size of each image?

Comment: Does it work for a while before running out of memory? You could have a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: The images are 1536x2048 loaded in an imageview with centercrop (it's almost fullscreen). On my Nexus 5 it doesn't crash, but on the S2 it crashed at the third image.

Comment: It's 12MB per image. You should prescale the images or scale them on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the `largeHeap` option from the manifest. It's not fixing the problem, it's sweeping the problem under the rug.

This is the problem

> The images are 1536x2048 loaded in an imageview

You shouldn't just try to load the image at maximum resolution, because, as you said, in a S2 for instance, which has a display of 800 x 480, what's the point?

Generally speaking, what you should do instead is load a bitmap into memory as big as you need it to be (in your case it should be as big as the ImageView). You can follow a very good tutorial for this in [the official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

> To avoid java.lang.OutOfMemory exceptions, check the dimensions of a bitmap before decoding it, unless you absolutely trust the source to provide you with predictably sized image data that comfortably fits within the available memory.

[....]

> For example, it’s not worth loading a 1024x768 pixel image into memory if it will eventually be displayed in a 128x96 pixel thumbnail in an ImageView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep this is the correct solution, but there are 2 problems: I use an asynctask to load the bitmap decoded using the code in the documentation. If works during the animation, but the first load, the one before the animation, shows some solid color. Some of the images quality is low after the scaling on the S2.

Comment: Can you paste some more code? Or even create a gist in with the relevant snippet.

Comment: Solved: the problem is that the ImageViews have match_parent as width, so if I try to fit the picture at runtime getting the ImageView size, it fails at the first load because the size is not yet known. I solved using Picasso adding a callback to set the alpha of the imaview on load.

Comment: Added a gist to the original question, might be useful for someone or someone could propose a better solution.